# NoneType object is not callable (Making lexer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, lexer, python-re

My Code:

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple

class TokenDef(namedtuple("TokenDef", ("name", "pattern", "value_filter"))):
    def __repr_(self):
        return "TokenType." + self.name
    
class TokenType(object):
    _defs = [
        TokenDef("plus", "+", None),
        TokenDef("minus", "-", None),
        TokenDef("aterisk", "*", None),
        TokenDef("slash", "/", None),

        TokenDef("left_paren", "(", None),
        TokenDef("right_paren", ")", None),
        
        TokenDef("integer", re.compile("[0-9]+"), int),
        TokenDef("whitespace", re.compile("[ \t]+"), None),
    ]

for def_ in TokenType._defs:
    setattr(TokenType, def_.name, def_)

token = namedtuple("Token", ("type", "value", "slice"))

def first_token(text, start=0):
    match_text = text[start:]
    token = None
    token_text = None
    
    for type_ in TokenType._defs:
        name, pattern, value_filter = type_
        
        if pattern is None:
            continue
            
        elif isinstance(pattern, str):
            
            if not match_text.startswith:
                continue 
            match_value = pattern
            
        else:
            match = pattern.match(match_text)
            
            if not match:
                continue
                
            match_value = match.group(0)
            
        if token_text is not None and len(token_text) >= len(match_value):
            continue 
            
        token_text = match_value
        
        if value_filter is not None:
            match_value = value_filter(match_value)
            
        token = token(type_, match_value, slice(start, start + len(token_text)))
        
    return token

first_token("6")
```

My Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\lexer.py", line 64, in <module>
    first_token("6")
  File ".\lexer.py", line 60, in first_token
    token = token(type_, match_value, slice(start, start + len(token_text)))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

why this is happening?

im trying to make a lexer, im going from a tutorial but i cant find where is my mistake. I am on jupyter notebook, using windows 10 pro and my python version is 3.9.0 (anaconda environment). And what is NoneType object? idk it is weird  but idk.

Comment: What is the tutorial you are following?

Comment: From the point where you wrote `token = None`, then `token` is None. So you can't call it.

Comment: You assigned `token = None`, then you try to call `token()`. Hence the error

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G78cTmgeUxI is my tuto. and this man also wrote token = None to.

Comment: @MarulForFlask ok, so then what is your question? Either the youtube video made a mistake, or you didn't exactly copy what they did. Make sure your other definition of `token` is correct.

Comment: "token = token(type_, match_value, slice(start, start + len(token_text)))" - here "token" is used as variable and also as function. is these names correct.

Comment: token is not a func, its a named tuple so its a variable. and in tuto its gives the int answer

Comment: @MarulForFlask `namedtuple` is a class factory. In the global scope, `token` is a class. Again, *double-check the tutorial*. In either case, the solution should be clear, don't use names that clash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your issue, you have two separate things called `token`

```
token = namedtuple("Token", ("type", "value", "slice"))
```

is what you want to be using as a call, rename the other token to something like my_token

change the following lines:

```
token = None
token = token(type_, match_value, slice(start, start + len(token_text)))
return token
```

to

```
my_token = None
my_token = token(type_, match_value, slice(start, start + len(token_text)))
return my_token
```

Comment: In: print(first_token("6"))
out: Token(type=TokenDef(name='plus', pattern='+', value_filter=None), value='+', slice=slice(0, 1, None))

Comment: @MarulForFlask I dont know what you are expecting as output, i fixed the error you were getting per your question

Comment: i dont expecting output as plus token, i exepting output as int and value was 6 if input was 6 output cant be "+" , it needs to be 6 and type is int.

Comment: @MarulForFlask all of this has nothing to do with your question

Comment: Yup i fixed it, problem was in pattern

Comment: @MarulForFlask don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your question